# SKPaymentTransaction's originalTransaction.transactionReceipt nil for restore on non-consumable

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

After calling restoreCompletedTransactions, for a non-consumable, the SKPaymentTransactions that are being returned seem to have nil in their originalTransaction.transactionReceipt property.  This is where the documentation says we should find the original transactionReceipt:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW2

Has anyone actually got this to be not nil - and if so, how?

In the returned SKPaymentTransactions, it looks like the actual correct transactionReceipt is in their transactionReceipt property (rather than their originalTransaction.transactionReceipt property).

Comment: The link is dead, ps.

Answer (score 3):

It has happened to me as well.

It's weird, but even though Apple states in its documentation that the `transactionReceipt` is found in `originalTransaction`, I found the `transactionReceipt` in the original `SKPaymentTransaction` class.

So, I have set up a little check before choosing which transaction to pass onwards:

```
SKPaymentTransaction *passedTransaction = nil;
if (transaction.transactionReceipt) {
    passedTransaction = transaction;
} else if (transaction.originalTransaction.transactionReceipt) {
    passedTransaction = transaction.originalTransaction;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Definitely seems like an error in the iOS SDK, but at least this allows us to verify the restored transactions.

Comment: Code is wrong. The type of 'transaction.transactionReceipt' is NSData*, not SKPaymentTransaction*. I'll leave it to you to rewrite, as there are two possible rewrites.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into the same issue. It would seem that the `transactionReceipt` on the `originalTransaction` will always return nil when restoring purchases. From the Discussion in the apple docs for `transactionReceipt`:

[Discussion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPaymentTransaction/originalTransaction)
The contents of this property are undefined except when `transactionState` is set to `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`.

Since during a restore (of a consumable item) the `transactionState` is always set to `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`, the `originalTransaction.transactionReceipt` property will always be nil.

Comment: Documentation states: "except when `transactionState` is set to `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`"
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPaymentTransaction/originalTransaction
Still have the same problem

Comment: Not only that, but originalTransaction is not identical to the original transaction!

Comment: @michaelFG Although NSLog states that transaction.originalTransaction.transactionReceipt is null, when I pass this value into a [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] variable, the correct receipt is added. Twilight zone...

Comment: @michaelFG Forget that comment. I had another code snippet which I had forgotten about, which actually uses transaction.transactionReceipt, as a back-up, to populate the relevant [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] receipt variables. So, yes, we should use transaction.transactionReceipt NOT originalTransaction.transactionReceipt for our restore purchases routine.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that that `transactionID` for `original` transaction is random. For different transactions can be the same original and **you shouldn't rely on original transaction if this is not restoring the purchases**.

Example from sandbox https://file.io/ReprC88b2K8Q. Check transactionID for original transactions.